# Working of MediaRecorder.start()

Tags: android

Can any one please explain me the working of `MediaRecorder.start()`. I wish to know how the recorded data is being saved to a file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Pompe's comment, this is the search query you will need to find the relevant code in the Android repositories:

```
site:kernel.org MediaRecorder.java
```

Comment: ya i checked it but they are using native method 'start()'. I checked .cpp defintion of the function but i couldn't understand the .cpp definition of the function.

Comment: @srikanth if you really want to know, then, I guess you have to learn C++.